# Python 3.4 accessing stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Apologies for my ineptness. When I run the following in IDLE on my python 3.4 install it fails.

```
>>> sys.stdout.fileno()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.stdout.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

This, seems to give something useful though...

```
>>> sys.stdout.fileno
<built-in method fileno of PseudoOutputFile object at 0x030927D0>
```

What obvious thing am I doing wrong?

thanks.

to cut a long story short I am actually trying to do this:

```
import os
os.write(1, "Hello world!\n")
```

But got the following error, so went down the route of trying out stdout

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    os.write(1, "Hello world!\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

and so the call to print sys.stdout.fileno() would give me the number, and I thought it might just be that it shouldn't be 1.

Comment: stdout is **always** fileno 1. Why do you need to access that programatically?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem however, not when running Python 3.4 from a terminal. Are you using an IDE console or similar perhaps?

Comment: I'm running it from the IDLE shell, btw, I just updated my post if it helps :)

Comment: @Neil: IDLE is not a standard environment. stdout is redirected, and certainly not bound to a standard stream. Why do you need to use `os.write()` here at all?

Comment: @eryksun: I had missed the `pyshell` and didn't know the name of the IDLE stdout-handling class.

Comment: well, that sucks :(

I ran it from notepad++ and it works. How are you supposed to try out io and system stuff from within IDLE or the shell?

Comment: @Neil: use an actual console. Windows doesn't provide one for GUI processes otherwise. Running with `python.exe` would provide a console.

Comment: ok, thanks, I just thought IDLE was a useful thing to use when starting out. Somebody put up an answer and I'll give a tick if the marks are required :)

Comment: @eryksun: and `os.write(1, ...)` should work too.

Comment: btw, what about the other error with os.write(1, "Hello world!\n") giving 'str' does not support the buffer interface? that fails in notepadd++ and from the python command line.

Comment: @Neil: You need to write bytes, not a unicode string.

Comment: Yes! I actually did that before (but when in IDLE) so got different errors and I forgot to prefix the string with b. This change from strings to byte arrays seems to be causing a few issues with methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDLE under windows is started with `pythonw.exe`, a console-less GUI. As such there is no `stdout` handle assigned, at all.

The shell window itself needs to redirect all stdout output to the GUI window, which is the `PseudoOutputFile` object you see.

If you wanted to experiment with writing to the `1` filenumber, you need to start IDLE with a console attached:

```
py -m idlelib
```

from a console should be enough to give you a process with an actual `sys.__stdout__` file handle, and writing with `os.write(1, ...)` will work.

Do remember that writing directly to a file handle requires **bytes**, not Unicode text. Encode your text or use a `b'...'` bytes literal.

Comment: @eryksun: wheee! and what filenumber does that new file object have then?

Comment: @eryksun: lets just say I am glad I don't develop on or for Windows.